# Eval loop syntax

Tags: perl

I'm practicing my Perl on codefights.

I've seen someone in a previous task feed Eval a list to make an array.

```
@a = map eval s/\B/*/gr,  0 .. 10000;
```

Yet, when i try and feed eval a list it give me an error

```
my ($a,$b,$c)=(1,2,3);
return 1 if eval "$a$_$b==$c", for qw "+ - / *";
```

This line also does not work as expected.

```
my ($a, $b, $c) = @_;
@aa=map eval "$a $_ $b", for qw "+ - / *";
```

However, this works

```
my ($a,$b,$c)=(1,2,3);
for (qw "+ - / *")
{
    return 1 if eval "$a$_$b==$c";
}
```

Can someone explain what the difference between the statements is?

Thanks

Comment: You've got a syntax error in `my ($a,$b,$c=(1,2,3);`. There's a `)` missing. Also, `$a` and `$b` are reserved global variables for `sort`. Don't use them in code. I hope you're learning this for one-liners, because the code you are writing is **not good Perl**.

Comment: Hi  simbabque , I've corrected the declaration error. Thanks for spotting it, it's not like that in the code, i added when writing the question for brevity. I know $a & $b are used for sort etc, however, this is a sample test.  Do you know the answer to my eval problem?

Comment: Your problem is not with `eval`. It's with misunderstanding the `map` operation. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstand what your first example does.

```
my @a = map eval s/\B/*/gr,  0 .. 10000;
```

This does not pass a list to `eval`. The `eval s/...//` is the argument to `map` in the non-block form. This becomes more clear when you add parentheses.

```
my @a = map( eval( s/\B/*/gr ),  0 .. 10000 );
```

It will call the `eval` statement for every number, and return a list of results, which gets assigned to `@a`. The code adds an asterisk after every other digit and builds a list of the resulting strings.

---

In this code, you again misunderstand what the `map` does.

```
my ($a, $b, $c) = @_;
@aa=map eval "$a $_ $b", for qw "+ - / *";
```

The `map` is essentially an in-place `for` loop. Adding a [*postfix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) `for` doesn't do anything useful here. `map` will already iterate all elements in your list. The list in this case is `"+", "-", "/", "*"`, which was created by the `qw//` operator.

Get rid of the `for` and it will work.

```
my ( $x, $y ) = ( 1, 2 );
my @results = map eval "$x $_ $y", qw "+ - / *";
```

The results of this are:

```
 3,
 -1,
 0.5,
 2
```

I suggest you [read up on `map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).

Comment: Does the for not generate a list, i've alway thought it did when used like this? e.g., my @aa=for 1..100;

Comment: @hoffmeister no, that is a syntax error. `perl -e 'my @foo = for 1 .. 100;'
syntax error at -e line 1, near "= for "`.

Comment: @hoffmeister the `..` is the operator that creates the list. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators.

Comment: Ok, i see how the map is working and my misunderstanding that for for loop does not make a list. but why does this not work? return 1 if eval "$a$_$b==$c" for qw "+ - / *";      but this does eval "$a$_$b==$c" and return 1 for qw "+ - / *"; ?

Comment: e.g., why is the if different to and?

Comment: *"The code replaces every other digit in the number with an asterisk"* No. It inserts an asterisk `*` between every pair of word characters (and every pair of non-word characters).

Comment: @Borodin right. I got that wrong. Butt it doesn't really matter what it does. I'll amend.

Comment: @hoffmeister because Perl does not allow you to have two different postfix keywords in one statement. When would this return 1? It's ambiguous. Your `and` statement will only execute the `+`, then it returns from your function. Don't try to write code like this. It's not readable. It's not cool. It's a pain to maintain this, and it doesn't give you any benefit. It's not even concise or idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks  simbabque for your help, much appreciated. I agree it can make code hard to read, i do try to keep it clean on real programs. But also, i find this stuff the fun part of perl :-/

Comment: @hoffmeister I agree, it can be fun. But as someone who teaches Perl let me tell you that it's not the best approach to learn. The Perl programming language owes parts of its sometimes bad reputation to code like this, and we are working hard on improving that. Anyway, have fun learning! :)